# Automatic mail sending with php

Tags: php, email, function, sendmail

I need to check once a day my `database` for old files uploaded by my clients, and remind them by `email` if their files are old than x day.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try a cron job. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Yes. Your question isn't specific enough. Build a function (grab the old file records from db, send email to your clients) and call it daily with a cronjob. If you have problems doing one of this steps, please ask and anyone will help you.

Answer (score 0):

A cronjob is just calls a call to a script on a given time.
You will need server access, Plesk or some control panel to set them.

Answer (score 0):

If you've never done cron jobs before try doing some example ones first, like adding data to a table every 30 minutes, or creating new txt or log files.

Then when you learnt cron jobs properly, like, the ubication of the files, file's permits, etc, create the cron with your job.

the thing is that if you setup your cron job daily, withouth perfectly knowing how is that done, then you would have to wait a lot to see if  it's working.

Also, run the files you are croning and make sure they behave as you expect, maybe there's a syntax error or something, so when the cron calls it, it fails and that's why it seems not to work.